# How to attach request parameters to current Android HttpUrlConnection call

Tags: android

I am able to send a request from an Android program to a remote server, but it seems the request has no parameters.  How do I attach parameters?

Here is my current code:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
    {

        String myUrl = theParams[0];
        final String myEmail = theParams[1];
        final String myPassword = theParams[2];

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()
        {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication( myEmail, myPassword.toCharArray());
            }
        });         

        String response = null;

        try 
        {
            final URL url = new URL(myUrl);

            final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("login", myEmail);
            conn.setRequestProperty("password", myPassword);

            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            final InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
            int readCount;
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((readCount = is.read(buffer)) > -1) 
            {
                builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, readCount));
            }

                response = builder.toString();      
            Log.d( "After call, response: " , " " + response);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }

        return response;
    }
```

So now I am not sure how to make the Authenticator password/login get attached to the request and get sent to the server. Any idea how I can accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply do this

```
final URL url = new URL(myUrl+"?login="+myEmail+"&password="+myPassword);
```

And you do not need the `setRequestProperty` lines. Those are actually setting your Http Request's properties and not the query params.

Comment: @Nikil but wouldn't that be a security flaw? Shouldn't the password somehow be hidden? I am not using https in my case. Thanks!

Comment: That is a different issue all together. Unless you have an encryption/decryption logic in place or you communicate over SSL, the credentials passed will always be in plain text.

Comment: @NikhilPatil, Hi there i would like to talk to you regarding adding parameters to a POST request in android